# Automatically add '>' at beginning of line following one starting with '>' when writing Markdown

Tags: formatting, filetype-markdown

When writing block quotes Markdown, I want to make vim act the same way it does with comment leaders and automatically start new lines with the '>'. I also want to be able to format text this way with `gq`. How can I do this? I set my formatoptions to `fo+=tacqw`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out vim handles block quotes in Markdown pretty much the way I asked for since at least version 7.4. It loads ftplugin/markdown.vim which sets '>' as a comment leader. It also adds the `t` flag to `formatoptions` and removes the `r` and `o` flags. That means if you write until the text is longer than `textwidth`, you get a new line that starts with `>`. But if you just press enter or add a new line with <kbd>o</kbd> or <kbd>O</kbd> you won't get the '>' on the new line. So if you want this functionality you have to override the file type plugin. You can do that by creating the file `.vim/after/ftplugin/markdown.vim` and adding `set formatoptions+=ro` to it.

My situation was that I had some paragraphs in a Markdown file that I wanted to turn into blockquotes by adding '>' at the start of every line. The paragraphs were already formatted so there were hard line breaks in them. I added '>' to the start of the first line and expected vim to make the whole paragraph commented if I used `gq` over it. Obviously that's not what `gq` does when you have a hard line break after what it recognizes as a comment. If it did, code written after a comment when programming would itself be commented out.

We can solve the problem if we join the lines of the paragraph by pressing `[count]`<kbd>J</kbd> where `[count]` is the number of lines to be joined. Then `gq` will format the paragraph as we want. If you have the `a` flag in `formatoptions` it's not necessary to use `gq` because the text is automatically reformatted.

Answer (score 4):

The 'mail' ft plugin (at least in vim 7.4) does this by making '>' a comment leader, like this:

```
set comments+=n:>
```

The "n:" means that they can be nested, as they often are in email. You probably don't need that, but might want some of the other options, like 'b' to require a space after the leader

```
set comments+=b:>
```

or, for just plain, do

```
set comments+=:>
```

Then, having 'q' in your formatoptions (like you already have) should flow with the block quote leader. Likewise, the 'c' in your formatoptions (as you also already have) will keep automatically placing the leader as you are typing text when the line wraps.

I'd also recommend adding 'r' and 'o' to your format options, so that creating new lines (enter in insert mode or 'o' or 'O' in normal mode) also automatically adds the leader:

```
set fo+=qcro
```

I expect those settings should work fine with markdown as well.

All of the flags for comment leaders are described at `:help format-comments` which may help you customize your settings further.

Comment: Thanks, this does create the right behavior for vim in general. But for some reason it doesn't work in my markdown files. They end with `.md` and vim seem to recognize them as markdown because there is syntax highlighting. I don't have any extra plugins, just the latest version of vim. Can vim treat different file types differently other than giving them the right syntax highlighting?

Comment: It does do more than syntax highlighting. Looking at vim7.4, it loads the ftplugin/markdown.vim file in the runtime path, which does set the block quote comment leader, but also unsets "r" and "o" from format options. Adding those back made things better for me.  Could you provide the output of `:set fo?`, `:set comments?` and the first 3 or 4 lines of `:version` for me? Those should help me track down what is going on.

Comment: I get `formatoptions=awtcqln` (so `r` and `o` is removed even though I added them in .vimrc), `comments=fb:*,fb:-,fb:+,n:>` (even though i put `set comments+=b:>` in .vimrc) and `version
VIM - Vi IMproved 8.0 (2016 Sep 12, compiled Aug  3 2017 18:29:25)
Included patches: 1-851
Compiled by Arch Linux`

Comment: If I simply start a line with '>' and keep typing until I get a new line, it works as it should. I can't reformat with `gq` though. Even if I can't add `r` to my `formatoptions` in .vimrc, if I add it when running vim it works – I get a new '>' when pressing enter. I can live without the latter but it would be really useful to be able to reformat a big chunk of text that I've pasted.

Comment: I think what is happening is that your vimrc settings are applying, and then the filetype plugin for markdown is running afterwards and changing the settings. Fortunately, autocommands may help. Try adding `autocmd BufRead,BufNew *.md set fo+=ro` to your vimrc. It should set formatoptions the way we want when opening an existing or new .md file. It seems to work for me. If it works for you too, I'll update my answer.

Comment: I tried adding the autocommand to vimrc but it doesn't work for neither new nor exisiting files. But I figured out why `gq` wasn't working as I wanted it to. There are hard line breaks in the paragraph I want to turn into a blockquote so even if I put '>' on the first line, only that line is seen by `gq` as part of the comment (which is obviously good when programming). If I join lines with by pressing `J` the '>' is added automatically the way I need.

Comment: Ok, I figured out how to override the Markdown file type plugin. Just create the file `.vim/after/ftplugin/markdown.vim` and add `set fo+=ro` to it. I learned it from [here](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Keep_your_vimrc_file_clean).

Comment: great! I forgot about the after directory. You should make that an answer and accept it. If you don't want to do that, I'll update this answer.